# Are all Macs one second off (after the leap second) or just mine?

Tags: macos

My mac is one second behind UTC as of yesterdays leap second. Is this effecting all Macs? Apple Watches? What's the deal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't find any info about when servers were updated. Mine is looking ok. Have you tried going to Preferences and turning off and back on Set time zone automatically using current location?

Comment: Mine is correct now. It would have been nice if it was coordinated with the official change. Have some points.